# Access element from style WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a style declared in a ResourceDictionary like so.

```
<Style x:Key="MapMarkerLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ActualWidth,                                              
                 Converter={StaticResource DoubleMultiplierConverter}, 
                                            ConverterParameter=-0.5}" 
                                Y="-62"></TranslateTransform>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the textblock

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MapMarkerLabelStyle}" />
```

And the converter:

```
public class DoubleMultiplierConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var originalValue = (double) value;
        var format = new NumberFormatInfo {NumberDecimalSeparator = "."};
        var multiplier = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter, format);
        return originalValue * multiplier;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the translate transform i need to access the textblock ActualWidth property but cant figure out how the binding should look.

Comment: Apparently you are trying to center the TextBlock at a given location. Did setting HorizontalAlignment to Center not work?

Comment: Setting a TranslateTransform to center a TextBlock might not be the best approach anyway. How about putting the TextBlock centered in a centered Panel of fixed size, and let WPF layout do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding is missing an appropriate source object. To bind to the TextBlock's `ActualWidth` property, you should set the `RelativeSource` like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MapMarkerLabelStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TranslateTransform
                X="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}
                            Converter={StaticResource DoubleMultiplierConverter}, 
                            ConverterParameter=-0.5}" 
                Y="-62"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: With AncestorType=TextBlock i get this error message instead: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem=null; target element is 'TranslateTransform' (HashCode=62126894); target property is 'X' (type 'Double')

Comment: Well, this works for me, though without your converter. Are you doing it in a Style that actually targets a TextBlock?

Comment: I added my converter in my original post. And my stylecode has targettype=TextBlock

Comment: i tried to remove the converter from the binding, i still get the same error

Comment: You get that error message once in the VS Output Window, but then the binding works... Simply ignore the error message.

Comment: I mean the converter seems to get the correct value, but why am i seeing these errors flooding my output window, im not a big fan of simple ignoring erros when i dont understand why they are occurring.

Comment: "System.Windows.Data Error: 4" is something you see sometimes. Here the Binding is established before the Style is actually applied to the TextBlock. Hence it complains once that there is no source object. So what.

Comment: Well then thats the cause and i can sleep well. If something that works as intended produces warning then this is a bug. A minor one sure, but i like my output window nice and clean

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 <TranslateTransform X="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                          Path=ActualWidth,                                              
             Converter={StaticResource DoubleMultiplierConverter}, 
             ConverterParameter=-0.5}" 
                     Y="-62">
 </TranslateTransform>
```

Comment: Then i get the following

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ActualWidth' property not found on 'object' ''TranslateTransform' (HashCode=48937974)'. BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem='TranslateTransform' (HashCode=48937974); target element is 'TranslateTransform' (HashCode=48937974); target property is 'X' (type 'Double')

Comment: I tried this. Binding looks fine. Seems like problem is in converter. It would be good if you share code of it.

Comment: `Self` means the TranslateTransform, not the TextBlock. It should be `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}`.

Comment: Nope, it means TextBlock only, because TargetType of style is TextBlock itself. Run this code and check it

Comment: @Parag You're wrong. And you didn't "try this". If you actually tried it, you would have noticed that it won't work. `RelativeSource Self` always means the object that the binding is applied to.

Comment: Try this simple example.  <Style x:Key="MapMarkerLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                          Path=Tag}">
                </Setter>
            </Style>      AND  <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MapMarkerLabelStyle}" Tag="Hello"/>

Comment: In above example, I have not set Text property  directly. I just set Tag property to Hello. In style, I bind to Self  and assign Tag to Text. See how it works

Comment: That is something different, because the Binding goes to the Text property of the TextBlock, not to the X property of the TranslateTransform. Carefully read the error message in the first comment to your answer. In short: **ActualWidth property not found on object TranslateTransform**

Comment: With AncestorType=TextBlock i get this error message instead: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem=null; target element is 'TranslateTransform' (HashCode=62126894); target property is 'X' (type 'Double')